# Why am I getting a SQL Server error on inserting value around 100 million

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm encountering problem when inserting a 100000000 value to column `amount`.

`amount` was defined in the database as decimal(13,5) but I cannot insert it.

Comment: And what is the error? And what is the value you try to insert?

Comment: You are asking people to *guess* what the error is or what your code does. You may be using a tool or not. You may have created your own program or not. You may be inserting *text* that can't be converted to decimals. Or there may be a value too large to fit into that field. It's impossible to help this way

Comment: Without knowing what you do people can't suggest eg using an error redirection in SSIS, a `try/catch` in C# or how to generate an error file with bcp

Comment: The definition of `decimal(p,s)` is that `p` (in your case: 13) stands the the **total** number of digits, of which `s` (in your case 5) are after the decimal point. So this datatype can hold numbers up to **8 digits** (***NOT*** 13!!) before and **5 digits** after the decimal separator - and you're trying to insert a number with **9** digits before the decimal point --> this will overflow. In the end: **works as designed** (and documented)

Comment: thank for the explanation  @marc_s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your datatype is `DECIMAL(13,5)` the max value you can store is `99999999.99999`.

In your case you are trying to store `100000000`, which is `0.00001` more than the max allowed value.

If you want to store it, you need to alter your column and increase the total length.

Comment: Thank you! Can you send me some link or reference regarding with the fact that you given.